# Should Backbone.js work with a version 533.3 Qt WebKit browser?

Tags: qt, backbone.js, webkit, qtwebkit

I have a website based on Backbone, Underscore and jQuery. It works fine in a Qt WebKit browser version 537.1 from Qt 4.8.1 (built as a standalone using Qt Creator). But in version 533.3 (which is what's shipped with Maya 2013), the Backbone model's `parse` function is never called after a `fetch`.

I got the browser versions from `alert(jQuery.browser.version)`.
I can't do Javascript debugging inside the browser, since it's part of a Maya plugin I'm working on. So I can't really pinpoint very well what's going on here.

So my question is, should I expect this not to work based on my browser version, or should I be looking for some other imcompatibility?

Comment: Turn your fetch into the following:
fetch({success: function () {alert("Success");}, error: function () {alert("Error");}}); and see what happens.

Comment: That bumped me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: It's great when it's that easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this code:

```
app.arrCollection.fetch();
app.arrWorkflowModel.fetch();
app.arrMetafieldsModel.fetch();
```

The arrCollection.fetch was working.
The arrWorkflowModel.fetch was failing, but not stopping the browser.
The arrMetafieldsModel.fetch was failing, and stopping the browser. This stoppage did not occur in later versions of the QWebView I tried.

Since this stuff is asynchronous, the third failure was stopping the browser before the first fetch could return anything.